# GNUplot mixes data producing output

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot the graph using gnuplot, but I am getting strange result. gnuplot for some reason makes larger gaps at two dates and places January 29th over January 31. The commands I use:

```
set terminal pngcairo size 1600,800 enhanced font "Helvetica,16"
set output 'Pic.png'
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
set xdata time
set format x '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
set title "Title"
set xlabel "Date"
set ylabel "Level"
set xtics timedate
set xtics rotate
nth(countCol,labelCol,n) = ((int(column(countCol)) % n == 0) ? stringcolumn(labelCol) : "")
plot 'data.txt' using 1:6:xtic(1) with l title 'V' lw 3, \
 'data.txt' using 1:2 with l title 'D' lw 3, \
 'data.txt' using 1:3 with l title 'H' lw 3
```

Output:

[image: output]

Note - nth is just for fun - I tried to get the xtick at every nth date, but failed. 
Behaviour is the same with gnuplot 5.0.3/64 and 5.2.2/64 on linux (I can provide the data file - do not see it fit to post 60 lines of data I use)

```
Data:
2018-01-27 16427682 16427855 -173 11.9176 1378438.77 2376.61
2018-01-28 16609257 16609139 118 11.9371 1391397.99 2398.96
2018-01-29 5185798 5342036 -156238 11.5996 447066.96 770.80
2018-01-30 0 0 0 11.432 0 0
2018-01-31 0 0 0 11.4451 0 0
2018-02-01 0 0 0 11.4493 0 0
2018-02-02 0 0 0 11.4545 0 0
2018-02-03 0 0 0 11.4491 0 0
2018-02-04 0 0 0 11.4169 0 0
2018-02-05 0 0 0 11.4167 0 0
2018-02-06 0 0 0 11.4124 0 0
2018-02-07 0 0 0 11.4013 0 0
2018-02-08 0 0 0 11.3926 0 0
2018-02-09 0 0 0 11.3861 0 0
2018-02-10 16958731 16273921 684810 11.8858 1426806.02 2460.01
2018-02-11 16498622 16498627 -5 11.854 1391818.96 2399.68
```

Comment: Remove the `xtic(1)`

Comment: No, the result (plot) is the same - the Jan 31th is before Jan 30th. The performance of x labels changed - now they are placed every 7th day (which could be OK, but stll not under my control), but - the plot begins at the date non existent in the data (Dec 28th, 2017).

Comment: Then please provide the data file

Comment: How can I attach it in order to have it unchanged? I noticed the strange behaviour also in the case of other data file, so I can provide both. Would the link to zip file for download fit?

Comment: Maybe the few lines around between Jan 28th and Feb 2nd are already enough to reproduce it? Otherwise you would need to upload the file somewhere and link it here. AFAIK there is no suggested upload site for data files

Comment: Your `timefmt` doesn't correspond to your data. Use `set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d'`

Comment: ups... I somehow overlooked it - before the data-set in question I played with data having time also. If it not qualifies for another question - how can I achieve the X labels to be put for every n-th entry? The function nth above does no function for some reason when referred to, for example: 
    plot 'data.txt' using 1:6:xtic(nth(1,1,10)) with l title 'V' lw 3 - no X labels are shown at all.

Comment: `set xtics n*24*60*60` and `plot "data.txt" u 1:6`

Comment: If I am correct - set xtics n*24*60*60 sets label every n*24*60*60 seconds where n - number of days in question. Is it possible to tie the xtics to the number of data series?